# How can a Julia package load its own package extension at runtime based on a condition?

Tags: julia

I would like to conditionally load a [package extension](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/#Conditional-loading-of-code-in-packages-(Extensions)) from within a function within a package. For an example of why this may be useful, say we have a package with a big function or CLI which does a lot of stuff. It has a heavy dependency which is only used very occasionally if a certain setting is set. I want to not require the dependency to be installed, but when the user requests the functionality I would like to prompt them to install the dependency and rerun. On rerunning, it should work normally.

The general layout of the code would be something like this:

```
module MyModule
function do_something(; user_config_flag=false)
    if user_config_flag
        if !(extension and its dependencies available)
            throw Error("message")
        end
        ext = load_extension()
        ext.do_something()
    end
end
end
```

Any ideas how to implement this pseudo-code in Julia-proper?

Answer (score 0):

You can't conditionally load the extension based on whether a flag is set. You can, however, use `Base.get_extension` to determine whether the extension is loaded and do some conditional logic based on that.

Another solution could be to define a function in `MyModule` and then add additional methods in the extension which extend the default implementation in the `MyModule`

```
module MyModule
function do_something(; flag = false)
    if flag
        ext = Base.get_extension(MyModule, :NameOfExtension)
        if isnothing(ext)
            throw Error("message")
        else
            ext.do_something()
        end
    end
end
end
```